# Criterion for dominant rational map and linear independence of global sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$ and  $L$ be an invertible sheaf on $X$ with no fixed part and $h^0(L) \ge n+1$. Choose $n+1$ linearly independent global sections $s_0,...,s_n$ on $X$. Is the rational map $f:X \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ defined by these $n+1$-sections, dominant? In other words, is it sufficient to choose $n+1$ *linearly independent* global sections to guarantee dominant rational map?

NB. If necessary assume that $X$ is non-singular.

Comment: No. Take $X=Y\times C$, $C$  a curve and $L$  Line bundle from $C$ pulled back to $X$ with $L$ very ample with many sections.

Answer (score 0):

The rational map $f$ is of course dominant to its image, but in genegral not to the $P^N$.For example, if $L$ is very ample, $dim H^0(L)$ might be very large and the map associated to this divisor is an embedding, not dominant.